# Cast int to float in F#

Tags: f#

Learning F#, the syntax is still quite foreign to me. How do I cast this integer to float?

```
let add x y =
    x + y

let j = 2
add 1.1 j
```

In C# Float + int= Float

```
float j = 1.1f + 5;
```

Comment: In C#, adding a `float` to a `double` returns a `double`. Your code is adding a `float` and an `int`.

Comment: While it seems obvious to have automatic, silent casting of values in a language, I do prefer the F# way of doing things. Avoids errors arising from automatic casting of types.

Comment: @lee -- That is funny. I meant to put int not double. :S fixed the Q.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

EDIT: misread the question...

I'm pretty sure that the `float()` function would do the job:

```
add 1.1 (float 2)
```

Answer (score 12):

First, the function you specified has type `int->int->int` which means it takes 2 `int`s and returns an `int`. If you want it to use `float`s you need to specify the type of one of the arguments:

```
let add (x : float) y = x + y
//add : float->float->float
```

As others have mentioned, you can cast to a `float` using the `float()` function:

```
float 2 //2 : float
```

If you are using numeric literals like in your example, you can just use `2.0` instead of `2` which has the `float` type.

```
add 1.1 2.0
```

Comment: Passing it two floats works fine. add 1.1 2.0 works without issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can convert to a float using the `float` function:

```
let add x y = x + (float y)
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `float` is a function, there is a certain elegance to

```
add 1.1 (j |> float)
```

On the face of it, that's not much better than `add 1.1 (float 2)`, but if you want to convert the result of a long calculation to a float, the forward pipe can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples showing the syntax for casting:

let x : int = 5 (cast x to be an integer)

let b : byte = byte x (cast b to be a byte)

Check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx

Comment: The first example isn't really a cast. It would be inferred to be an int anyway.